# R shiny downloadHandler does nothing

Tags: r, shiny

I have problem using R 4.1.1 and shiny 1.7.1 on my Windows 10. After creating simple button with download action it doesn't do anything.

Here is my code sample:

```
output$download_template_action <- downloadHandler(
  filename = 'template.csv',
  content = function(file) {
    write.csv(colnames(iris[, -5]), file, row.names = FALSE)
  } 
)

...

actionButton('download_template_action', 'Download template')
```

There is no error and no other action at all. What am I missing?

I have been trying to download the csv via RStudio, Chrome and FFox

Comment: Please take a look at the [documentation](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/downloadHandler.html). You should use a [`downloadButton`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/downloadButton.html) not an `actionButton`.

Comment: @Kitswas Thank you, that was it :) silly me